# Unity settings has platform dependent collision with GIT

Tags: android, git, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, dependency-resolver

I'm using `Unity 2019.1.14f1`, `Play Services Resolver 1.2.124` and `git` on Windows and MacOS.

Some `*.aar` files and `ProjectSettings/AndroidResolverDependencies.xml` contains different slash symbols for different operation systems so I can't commit or ignore them because It'll be impossible to build apk without the files.

Upgrading Play Services Resolver to 1.2.125 doesn't change anything. What should I do?

Comment: UPD: I asked developers: https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/279

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to 1.2.127 fixed the issue